# Cant find whats wrong with the line

Tags: php, web

i cant find whats wrong. Something happens after the first SESSION.

```
'SELECT m1.id, m1.title, m1.timestamp, count(m2.id) AS reps, users.id AS userid, users.username FROM pm AS m1, pm AS m2,users WHERE ((m1.user1="'.$_SESSION['user'].'" AND m1.user1read="no" AND users.id=m1.user2) OR (m1.user2="'.$_SESSION['user'].'" AND m1.user2read="no" users.id=m1.user1)) AND m1.id2="1" AND m2.id=m1.id group by m1.id ORDER BY m1.id DESC');
```

Comment: What error message do you get then? You say "something happens", what happens? If you can't describe your problem, then how do you expect us to guess what it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have ' in beginning of the string, also AND m1.id2="1" is missing begining parenthesis. additionally where is users.id coming from?

```
'SELECT m1.id, m1.title, m1.timestamp, count(m2.id) AS reps, users.id AS   
(
    (m1.user1="'.$_SESSION['user'].'" AND m1.user1read="no" AND users.id=m1.user2) 
    OR 
    (m1.user2="'.$_SESSION['user'].'" AND m1.user2read="no" users.id=m1.user1)
) 
AND m1.id2="1" AND m2.id=m1.id group by m1.id ORDER BY m1.id DESC');
```